# AM/PM displaying as tt in Excel Export

Tags: datetime, radgrid, date-formatting

I have a GridDateTimeColumn in my RadGrid. I am using a custom method to Export to Excel. When I export the date is exported as "2/2/2017 1:38:34 tt". Instead of showing AM or PM it just says tt at the end.

```
createdColumn.DataFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Then I changed the column's Number Format (which was displaying date ) to "Text". Which solved my problem.

ASPX

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn HeaderText="Create Date" HeaderStyle-Width="13%" 
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="CreateDateDesc" DataField="CreateDate" DataType="System.String" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}" ></telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

C#

```
protected void radGrdOrderHistory_InfrastructureExporting(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridInfrastructureExportingEventArgs e)
{
 Telerik.Web.UI.ExportInfrastructure.Table tbl = e.ExportStructure.Tables[0];
 foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.ExportInfrastructure.Cell cell in tbl.Columns[9].Cells)
  {
     cell.Format = "@";
  }
}
```

Comment: you asked a question in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I believe changing "tt" to "AM/PM" is sufficient. I had the same issue using EPPlus which led me [here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time-formatting) with the following image:

[image: Custom time formatting examples]

It fixed my issue without changing the column type.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I have made below change to fix it. This replaced the `tt` with `AM/PM`.

```
createdColumn.DataFormatString.Replace("tt","AM/PM")
```

Hope this helps.